# Crop image from image with Libgdx

Tags: image, libgdx

I'm developing an application for Android with Libgdx.
I would like to get the effect produced in the image by using two images.
Any suggestions? The guides that I found did not help to solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can just be achieved using the alpha channel of the image? Why do you need a second image? If you really need two images you could just use a shader to achieve it [Link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders), a good tutorial to get started can be found [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Shaders).

Comment: I tried it with alpha channel ... I get a clear image in the stencil, but outside it the image does not disappear, but it has a transparency effect.

Comment: Do you have an example of this. Because if you set the alpha to 0 the region should be fully transparent.